# Key-value info box with 2 columns. Not a table

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I want to create an info box similar to this:

```
-----------------------------------
items           item1
                item2
                item3
-----------------------------------
total price     $123
-----------------------------------
note            blah-blah-blah-blah
                blah-blah-blah-blah
                blah-blah-blah-blah
-----------------------------------
payment status  pending
-----------------------------------
ship to        TR, City1, name1 st.
               123, building A
-----------------------------------
```

A simple solution is preferable. The one with 'table' isn't what I'm looking for.

It could be done via `flex`. And/or with 'li', 'dl'.

But how?

Comment: ...and **why** is this NOT a `table`?

Comment: @Paulie_D You said "why do you want to use table, don't use it". And I said the same thing - I don't want table.

Comment: So if you don't want a table (and i can't think why since it clearly IS a table) that does not mean you shouldn't research and attempt other options (CSS-Tables/Css-Grid for two). We don't do "requirement dump questions", **you** are supposed to try something and we help when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 350px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 2px dashed;
}

.container:last-child {
    border-bottom: 2px dashed;
}

.container .item {
    width: 50%;
}

.container .value {
    width: 50%;
}

.container .value ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.container .value .city {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.container .value .st {
    color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">items</div>
        <div class="value">
            <ul>
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>item2</li>
                <li>item3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">total price</div>
        <div class="value">
            <p>$123</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">note</div>
        <div class="value">
            <p>blah-blah-blah-blah blah-blah-blah-blah blah-blah-blah-blah</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">payment status</div>
        <div class="value">
            <p>pending</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item">ship to</div>
        <div class="value">
            <p>TR, <span class="city">City1</span>, name1 st.<span class="st">123</span>
                , building A</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```